# How to linearize this difficult constraint with binary variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to linearize the constraint $y_i \cdot q_i \leq y_i \cdot a$ where $a$ is constant, $y_i$ is a binary variable and $q_i$ is a continuous non negative variable.

Thanks !

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @copper.hat Writing things in linear programming constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively $y_i$ implies $q_i \leq a$, which is $q_i \leq a \cdot y_i + M(1-y_i)$ where $M$ is your favorite sufficiently-large small-M constant (i.e, what normally but dangerously is called a big-M constant).

Comment: Thanks, I have edited your answer because my upper bound on $q_i$ is more "significant" when  $y_i =0$ . I think it should work, don't you think?

Comment: I don't see any change in your edit, so I can only assume I had a typo then in my initial version.

Comment: I  multiplied $a$ by $y_i$, that's indeed the change